# Permute transposition and derivative + Norm question

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, banach-spaces, vector-analysis

I have two questions:

1. In general, what are the conditions to permute transposition  and derivative:
   $$[x^{\prime}(t)]^{T}=[x^{T}(t)]^{\prime}$$
2. Is it correct to writ:  $\quad$ $\mathbb{R}^{n}=\mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R}).\mathbb{R}^{n}$

   so if: $\quad$  $x=Py$

   then  $\quad$$\|x\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}=\left\|P y\right\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}<\|P\|_{\mathbb{M}_{n}}\|y\|_{\mathbb{R}^{n}}$

Thank you for your justifications and explanations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. In finite dimensional row and column vectors, transposition is linear (and bounded, continuous) and limits interchange with this operation. In more general vector spaces, you would have to define what transposition or something similar is, and in rare situations that operation might not be bounded=continuous.
2. Yes. As long as the matrix norm is associated to the vector norm. There are many different vector space norms and associated and unassociated matrix norms, and not for every combination do you get that inequality (which is not strict in general for the standard situation of associated norms).

Comment: Thank you. Can I ask you for a counterexample showing that it isn't correct if the matrix norm is not associated with the vector norm

Comment: You can take any matrix norm and scale it down. It becomes more complicated if you put conditions on the norm such as being sub-multiplicative. Take $y=\pmatrix{1//1}$ and $P=\pmatrix{1&1\\1&0}$ and the maximum norm for the vectors and the spectral norm for the matrix. Then the matrix norm is the greater root of $\rho^4-3\rho^2+1=0$, that is $\|P\|_{2,op}=\rho=\sqrt{\frac{3+\sqrt5}2}=\frac{1+\sqrt5}2<2$ while $\|y\|_\infty=1$ and $\|x\|_\infty=2$.

Comment: Respect, maybe I'll be a little bit greedy because I have another question concerning norms, and you are a person who I can rely on :)

 In general, is it correct if we have $\quad$ $0<t<s$ and $A \in \mathbb{M}_{n}(\mathbb{R})$ is that imply: $\|e^{tA}\|<\left\|e^{sA} \right\|$

I review some properties of the exponential matrix and I didn't find such a proposition.

Comment: Take a rotation matrix and some rectangular norm, like the row-sum norm, then $\|e^{Jt}\|_\infty=|\cos(t)|+|\sin(t)|=\sqrt{1+|\sin(2t)|}$ is periodically oscillating.

Comment: - sorry, I didn't understand your example.
I research for the exponential of the matrix of rotation and I found this useful answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1119602/730650
- "periodically oscillating" is that mean we couldn't compare the two norm ?

Comment: $J$ is a matrix with $J^2=-I$, usually $J=\pmatrix{0&-1\\1&0}$. Then $e^{tJ}=\pmatrix{\cos(t)&-\sin(t)\\\sin(t)&\cos(t)}$ with the said norm. You were conjecturing a monotonous behavior in $t$, that it is oscillating contradicts that. I do not know where the speculation on the form of $\exp(t\exp(\theta J))$, like in the linked answer, would be helpful in that.

Comment: Oh, I thought J was the rotation matrix, it was a notation misunderstanding, that why I tried to find the exponential of the rotation matrix. It's clear now, thank you for your help.